# replace pattern matching

Tags: text-processing, replace

I want to replace part of a file's data, with data from another file.

Suppose `file1` has data as is written below and `file2` has some data I want to store replace `file1` data from `file2` from starting word, `// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++` and the end word `// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++`.

#### file 1

```
ANJALI
NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WE WILL BE ON LEAVE FOR TODAY 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

PREETI
MONA
```

#### file 2

```
MANISH
MADHVI

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WELCOME  ALL 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

NISHA
TUSHAR
```

#### file 3 As OUTPUT we want

```
ANJALI
NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WELCOME  ALL 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

PREETI
MONA
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question, but I don't understand the last sentence. Can you update your question, currently it sounds like you want multiple lines to be replaced but you give the far more simple example updating a single line.

Comment: You can just edit your question, no need to do a complete repost http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157647/33055

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -v pat="$(awk '/SETTINGS START/,/SETTINGS END/' file2)" -v p=1 '
    /SETTINGS START/{p=0};p;/SETTINGS END/{print pat;p=1}' file1 > file3
ANJALI
NISHA

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS START +++ 

WELCOME  ALL 

// +++ CUSTOMIZATION SETTINGS END +++ 

PREETI
MONA
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gnouc but its not working at my end it is showing an error     "Illegal variable name "